# Adding new entity

Tags: jhipster

I'm new on using JHipster, I'm able to add new entity through `jhipster import-jdl myentity.jh`

The problem is my entity only shows up when I load the app through `npm start` which refers to [localhost:9000](http://localhost:9000)

I want it to show on my [localhost:8080](http://localhost:8080) so I don't need to start another terminal. I've followed similar step through their tutorial video on [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VQ_SVkaXbs) but can't get the same result.
[No entity image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CaFR.png)

What i've did so far

1. `gradle clean bootRun -Pdev -Pwebpack`
2. ``` for f in ``ls .jhipster``; do jhipster entity ${f%.*} --force ; done ``` (regenerate all the entities)

Is there anything I miss while adding new entity?

Comment: Your step 2 is not needed when using JDL. Please read the official docs for your point about the 2 servers, https://www.jhipster.tech/development/ and https://www.jhipster.tech/using-angular/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue is fixed by running `npm install`

Now my entities is showed up on `localhost:8080`